# Targeting Text in Input for CSS

Tags: css

I'm building a contact form.  Currently I have a text box set up with a top and bottom padding.  My text looks like this.
[image]

As you can see, I don't have any padding on the sides of the text of my input boxes which looks quite ugly.  However if I modify my css in reguards to my input boxes, it adds padding to the actual box instead of the text itself, pushing things over:

[image]

I'm sure I could do something like give a negative margin to the boxes to offset the padding and adjust the width, but I'd rather figure out how to target the text within the input itself. I know this is a little hard to visualize, so here's my intended result:

[image]

Here's my current CSS.

```
/* top two boxes */
input
{
width: 49.9%;
font-size: 24px;
padding-top: 12px;
padding-bottom: 12px;
}

/* textarea CSS*/
textarea
{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
font-size: 24px;
}
```

Is there some sort of selector I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

box-sizing: border-box? The border-box value (as opposed to the content-box default) makes the final rendered box the declared width, and any border and padding cut inside the box.
Use -moz-box-sizing for firefox.

Comment: I'm not looking to have no padding; I want padding around the text _within_ my inputs, not the input element itself, because it will cause what happened in the second picture.  I'm already aware of the default padding.

Comment: "I'm sure I could do something like give a negative margin to the boxes to offset the padding and adjust the width, but I'd rather figure out how to target the text within the input itself."

Comment: That did the trick!  If you edit your answer and include it I'll upvote and select as the answer, thanks.

Comment: OK but I think it's not very good choice because content-box is preferred by W3C.